# How can I remove /overwrite /filter in a listview?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have the codes below which will populate results from database to listview.
I have datas in the database that has similar names 
now my problem is I want to display only one among the similar names into my listview.
How should I implement that in codes below?

```
String query = "SELECT  _id, name, symptoms1, symptoms2 FROM hsdisease WHERE symptoms2 LIKE?";  
// Append as many WHERE clauses as necessary
for(int x= 0; x<HerbalSuggesstionsArray.length - 1; x++) {
    query += " OR symptoms2 LIKE ?";                        
}
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, HerbalSuggesstionsArray);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.herbalsuggestion_list_item,
        cursor,           
        new String[] {"name", "symptoms1" },
        new int[] {R.id.hsname, R.id.hssymptoms} );
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i dont see any question mark here...

Comment: use a FilterQueryProvider

Comment: sir how can i implement FilterQueryProvider in my codes above? sorry i'm still newbie in android programming

Comment: use SimpleCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider